# C# - Save the last selected file names after closing DialogBox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, openfiledialog

I have a button which will open a file dialog and choose 2 certificates.
[image]  After i click the button a windows will be shown from where i choose two certificates.[image]

I click Open so i will get this two certs.  What i want to do is that after i click Open and click again the Select Certificate button instead the empty filename textbox like this [image] I want the last selection to be saved.
Is it possible such a thing?

Comment: You mean you want to automatically re-select the previously selected items?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I know how to remember the directory, but not how to find the selected files.

Comment: Save the FileName string & set it before opening a second time. Note that there is a bug with this only setting part of the file name - workaround here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163784/default-name-with-openfiledialog-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenFileDialog has a [FileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) property
Just assign it

Comment: I assign the file names but it says: Property FileNames is ReadOnly

Comment: Shoot - the documentation says get set

Comment: File**Names** is ReadOnly, but FileName isn't.

Comment: @drgmak was this the answer that helped you? then you might considering to mark it also.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the FileName property when you create the dialog. It supports multiple files if you include quotes around the file names (full paths). See the example below:

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog
{
    Multiselect = true,
    FileName = @"""C:\example.txt"" ""C:\example2.txt"""
};
```